# Struggling with .populate: works when reference is in array, fails when not

Tags: mongoose

I am struggling with using .populate on an existing mongo collection.

When I declare my schema as follows:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
'postOwner': [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
'group': [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }],
'title': String,
'body': String
});
```

With a dataset that looks something like this

```
Post: {
  __v: 2,
  _id: ObjectId("4ffcaa5a3b02181d2900001b"),
  body: "Some fabulous text",
  group: ObjectId("4fce5e460f49788e06000005"),
  title: "This is a title",
  owner: ObjectId("4fce5e460f49788e062343205")
}
```

The following query works well, except that it returns the referenced group and postOwner fields as a single element array:

```
                PostSchema
                .find( {group: {$in: groups}})
                .sort('-createdAt')
                .populate('postOwner', 'email firstName lastName')
                .populate('group', 'groupName')
                .exec(function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Bad news bears.');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Huzzah');
                    }
                });
```

This creates some minor, but workable hassles on the front end since I always need to reference element 0 in the returned array. If I take the logical step of removing the array from the schema, so it looks like this:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
'postOwner': { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
'group': { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' },
'title': String,
'body': String
});
```

with the data remaining exactly the same, the same query returns nothing at all (not even the ObjectID) for `group` or `postOwner`.

I can live with referencing the first element of an array to make my references work, but it seems sub-optimal and I hate hard-coding array references all over my front end.

What am I missing to define my schema "correctly" and still have my references work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The JSON in your schema is malformed. The last property should not be followed by a comma. Sometimes this can cause weird behaviour in JavaScript, though it usually should cause the entire object to be undefined. Depending on how the Schema constructor handles errors, this might be why you're not getting the behaviour you're expecting. 
A stop-gap measure might also be to not send the `postOwner` array down to the client, but rather `postOwner[0]`. It's not optimal, and still hardcoded, but if you only need that element then you could clean up your front end like that.

Comment: Oops, that was a late-night copy/paste error. The JSON in my schema does not contain the extra comma. I've corrected above.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe post your model code as well for TimeLinePost?

Comment: Corrected above... All schemas/data reference the same model. Sorry about a poor copy/paste/edit job on my part. I wanted to remove the extra stuff from the model to make it more clear.